# How to add a .jar file into Android studio (version 0.4.0) project

Tags: android, ksoap2

How to add a jar file into a Android studio project. 
For example I am trying to add ksoap2-android-assembly-3.1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
into a project. Dont see an option anywhere to add the jar file into the project so as to access the library functions within it.

Answer (score 17):

Create a **libs** folder in your project and copy the jar into it. In the project view, right-click on the jar and choose **Add as Library**.

Answer (score 0):

This is android `libs >> Open Libraries settings >> add jar.`

For more information, check the stack-overflow link

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

Thanks